# use static price at place of original price in Magento

Tags: magento

In Magento,I have created an attribute for product price as my_price_attribute.

If cusomer who logged in belongs to perticular group,then I want to show my_price_attribute value at place of original price and use my_price_attribute value to cart else i will have to dislay both prices but use original price to cart.
How can i do this?

Comment: are you want to show  this  price  also in addtocart

Comment: Yes,i want to use that price as product price.

Comment: it is use special_price instead of  my_price_attribute,for idea

Comment: Sorry there is updation in question,If person belongs to perticular group,then i have to show my_price_attribute as price else show both prices but apply original price.

Comment: you means perticular group as Customer group?

Comment: Yes i have customer group and i want if customer belong to that group then my attribute price is charged else original price is charged but both prices gets displayed.

Answer (score 0):

Happy, Magento have Provide own feature for your type  requirement.

Use Price **Group Price** ,`Here you can set according to customer group`
[image]

Comment: For bundle products,we can apply discount in percent not fixed price.

Comment: And in simple products we can fix the price but can not provide the discount percent.